# Ограничить вводимые данные. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Пытался уже решить этот вопрос, но никак не получаеться решить проблему.

Вопрос был у меня такой:
Хочу задать условия («Чтобы нельзя было указывать в таблица "Расписание" одновременно перебывание в разных аудитория на одном уроке (моего учителя в табл нагрузка»)

Я, создал уникальный индекс и у меня получаеться решить проблему дублирования вводимых данных. Одноко, когда я задаю,что мой учитель преподает к примеру ( на 1 уроке,в аудитории 111 и в понедельник) , а потом снова задаю ( на 1 уроке,в аудитории 112 и в понедельник) Тут Допускаеться ввод данных в обоих случаях, а у меня как бы учитель не может вести одновременно в разных аудиториях свой предмет... Как можно ограничить это ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сложные проверки можно делать в хранимых  процедурах. Просто делайте запрос в хранимой процедуре есть ли пересечения по аудитории,  времени,  учителям.  Если есть - возвращайтесь ексепшен, код или текст ошибки - в зависимости от того как удобнее

Comment: Как именно нужно задать условия, не могу понять.
Можете пример привести пожалуйста.

Comment: так заджойните таблицы Учитель, Нагрузка, Расписание и найдите сколько уникальных комбинаций (id учителя, день недели, урок, аудитория). Если где-то больше 1 - ошибка

Comment: Вот так вывожу свои уникальные комбинации. Чего-то не получается сделать проверку...

select id_учитель,урок,день_недели,аудитория from нагрузка 

 join учитель using(id_учитель)

 join расписание using(id_нагрузка)

 group by id_учитель,укрок,день_неделя,аудитория

Comment: А сумму еще добавьте - сколько раз каждая комбинация повторяется - count

Comment: Блин, не могу понять как задать - это условие. Много вариантов перепробывал...

Comment: @Александр Условие зависит от того, где именно вы его собирались задать. Если например вы делаете проверку перед созданием записи (в вызывающей процедуре или в before row триггере) то вам надо проверить только конкретного учителя в конкретный день/урок. `select count(1)
 from нагрузка
 join расписание using(id_нагрузка) 
 where id_учитель = (select id_учитель from нагрузка where id_нагрузки= ?)
   and урок = ? and день_недели = ? and аудитория != ?
 `

Comment: `CREATE or replace FUNCTION raspi5()
  RETURNS Trigger 
AS $$
DECLARE
 arg_yrok integer;
    arg_nag integer;
 arg_room integer;
 arg_day char;
BEGIN
 arg_yrok := TG_ARGV[0];
 arg_nag   := TG_ARGV[1];
 arg_room := TG_ARGV[2];
 arg_day := TG_ARGV[3];

select count(1) from нагрузка join расписание using(id_нагрузка) where id_учитель = (select id_учитель from нагрузка where new.id_нагрузки= arg_nag and урок = arg_yrok and день_недели = arg_day and аудитория != arg_room
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgSQL;`

Comment: @Mike   CREATE TRIGGER ch_raspisanue1
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON расписание
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE raspi5(урок,id_нагрузка,аудитория,день_недели);

Comment: Работаю в Postgresql, но я думаю - это не важно. Вот сделал как вы говорили триггер, но он на любой ввод данных ругаеться почему-то

Comment: @Александр Что то я не вижу, что бы как либо использовали значение, выданное запросом или хотя бы сохраняли его где то. И вообще сомневаюсь, что в процедуре можно писать запрос, значение которого никуда не сохраняется.

Comment: @Mike Понять, что-то не могу как именно сделать этот триггер. 
Можете подсказать как правильно было бы сделать. Просто мне очень нужно это ограничения...